# Featured Templates not working in Microsoft PowerPoint, Excel, and Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-office

I do not know when exactly this became an issue, but Microsoft PowerPoint, Excel, and Visio 2013 are all having a problem with featured templates not loading. Microsoft Word and Publisher's featured templates are loading just fine. Whenever I launch either one of these three programs, the main screen loads with the message, "We don't have any featured templates right now." I refuse to believe that there would never be any featured templates, so what is the problem?

In PowerPoint, the message pops up, but continues trying to load the "Welcome to PowerPoint" and "Create an Office Mix" templates. I have already downloaded the "Welcome to PowerPoint" template, so clicking on the first of two spinners opens it, but clicking on the second opens a box that says "Something went wrong while downloading your template."

[image: PowerPoint]

Excel behaves in the same manner as Word: loading existing templates works just fine, but trying to load ones where the spinner is present fails.

[image: Excel]

When you launch Visio, a bunch of the "template loading" spinners appear, but they soon disappear, and you are left with this.

[image: Visio]

Does anyone know what could have caused this and how to fix it? I have checked this on my mom's computer as well, and she runs into the same issue, with the exception of Visio since she does not have it installed. We are both running Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

Comment: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)

Comment: @DavidPostill I am hesitant to run a repair because the last time I did that, it took a small problem I was having with Office and completely destroyed it, resulting in a completely dysfunctional MS Office.

Comment: <Shrug> it's only a suggestion. It's up to you whether you take it or not.

Comment: We shall see. I may do it if I am unable to determine whether or not a faulty update is responsible, which I think is the problem. It is somewhat unlikely that two different computers would have their copies of Office go corrupt in the same way, right?

Comment: @DavidPostill I ran a repair of Office on both computers, and on both computers, the problem remains. I am absolutely certain now that the problem is caused by a faulty update, but I do not know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have resolved itself since the time that I posted this question. Microsoft Office Featured Templates are once again working they way they are supposed to on my computer.